# How can I upload CSV file in QGIS Desktop App?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, indentationerror

Please see link : 
http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/building_a_python_plugin.html

I am using the same process for uploading a CSV file in a folder but it gives me an error.

I am using this code:

```
def select_output_file(self):

    filename = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self.dlg, "Select output file ","", '*.txt')
    self.dlg.lineEdit.setText(filename)
```

It gives the error:

> Couldn't load plugin Importtool due to an error when calling its classFactory() method
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGISWI~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 219, in startPlugin  plugins[packageName] = package.classFactory(iface)
>
> File "C:/Users/n/.qgis2/python/plugins\Importtool__init__.py", line 34, in classFactory  from .Import_tool import Importtool
>     File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGISWI~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 478, in _import
>
> mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
>
> File "C:/Users/n/.qgis2/python/plugins\Importtool\Import_tool.py", line 71
>       self.dlg.lineEdit.clear()
>
> IndentationError: unexpected indent

Please see below image. [image]

Comment: The error relates to your indentation, try fixing that and see how it goes? I've edited your question and correctly fixed the indentation.

Comment: Hi Joseph ,
thanks for your reply . I didn't get you . what do you mean by indentation eroor ? I am not able to rectify the error . Please tell me in detail .

Comment: The indentation is the "space" at the beginning of a line code. If you compare the code just above yours, you see that the line just after the "def unload" is indented, with a tab. Try this with your code.

Comment: Hi vale, I have removed "space" at the beginning of a line code. But still its give same error.

Comment: You need to add spaces at the beginning of your line codes below the def line. Check your picture above: the code you wrote hasn't "space" at the beginning of the lines below the "def select_output". Compare with the other def statements in the code

Comment: I have written code same as above but still it give same error. I have uploaded file in Dropbox Import_tool,py file. please see the file . https://www.dropbox.com/s/daof61lldrxft3j/Import_tool.py?dl=0